# How to revert a Map<String, Collection<XYZ>> to Map<XYZ, Collection<String>> using streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a map like this `Map<String, Collection<XYZ>>` which I iterated through traditional for each loop to get a result like `Map<XYZ, Collection<String>>` but the same I couldn't do it with stream on map. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Show us how you do it in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by flattening your input Map into pairs of `String` and `XYZ`, and then collecting them into the desired output `Map`:

```
Map<String, Collection<XYZ>> input = ...
Map<XYZ, List<String>> output = 
   input.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .flatMap(e -> e.getValue()
                       .stream()
                       .map(xyz -> new SimpleEntry<XYZ,String>(xyz,e.getKey())))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                       Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue,
                                                          Collectors.toList())));
```

Note that the values in the output `Map` are `List`s instead of `Collection`s. I hope you don't mind (since `List`s are also `Collection`s).

Comment: Recently I found some similar solutions(not questions) like this, good to learn from you.